# UILabel not responding to touch

Tags: iphone

```
    label_win3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 358, 210,15)];
            label_win3.text=@"Click here";
            label_win3.textColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
            label_win3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            label_win3.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 14.0];
            label_win3.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;

            label_win3.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


        [self.view addSubview:label_win3];



- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];


    if([touch view]==label_win3) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShowRegistration" object:nil];}

     }
```

Comment: Seriously? You just dump your code there without any explanation or hint at a question? Do you believe we are psychic? Your code only states a fact: labels do not accept user interaction. This is by design. Labels are labels, not buttons, you have to handle events yourself. If you want more than that consider revising your question to show that you have at least made something of an effort on your part.

Comment: why not?  I see it has .userInteractionEnabled property.

Comment: Of course, I am handling the event myself. That what the touchbegan method use for.  If touch equivalent label_win3 view then trigger an action.

Answer (score 2):

UILabels should and cannot respond to touch.

TextViews, TextFields, and Buttons all respond to touch.

Read the documentation if you are uncertain whether a particular UI element can have user interaction.

Comment: why not? I see it has .userInteractionEnabled property.

Answer (score 1):

Having `userInteractionEnabled` means that touches are passed to the view. It does not mean that the view (`UILabel`) does something with them. UILabel is a very lightweight class. If you want to respond to touches on a UILabel, attach a `UIGestureRecognizer` to it, subclass it or use a custom `UIButton`. Many times, `UIGestureRecognizer` is the best solution for this (though you should use a `UIButton` whenever you can; it includes many specialized behaviors that are a pain to reproduce).

In any case, there is no reason for you to expect that your `touchesBegan:withEvent:` would be called. You were not touched. The UILabel was touched, and *its* `touchesBegan:withEvent:` was called. It then did nothing with that event as designed.

Jasarien is also correct that your question is very incomplete and confusing, but I think we've pieced it together.